# Validating User Input for Specific Char

Tags: c

I'm creating a program that runs a card game, I need to get a trump suit (H, D, S, C) and validate user input. I am able to catch invalid stuff like j or 3, but if they enter HH, or SS (which is invalid) it thinks it's correct.

I've tried using strlen to see if there's more chars, and I thought maybe I could check if the buffer has other garbage in it, but have no idea how to do that.  I also tried doing something like `while(scanf(" %c", &trump) != 1`, but that didn't work. I've only been coding in c for a week.

my tump function

```
char getTrump(){
  char trump;
  char ch;

  char correct = 1;
  while(correct == 1){
    printf("Please choose a trump suit (H, D, S, C): ");
    scanf(" %c", &trump);
    while(getchar() != '\n');

    if(isValidSuit(trump) == 1){
      printf("Correct\n");
      return trump;
      correct = 0;
    }else{
      printf("Please enter a valid suit.\n");
    }
  }
}
```

and if it helps my isValidSuit function (which has to have a char as a parameter)

```
int isValidSuit(char c){
  char suits[] = {'H', 'D', 'S', 'C'};

  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    if(suits[i] == c){
      return 1;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

an example of running it:

```
Please choose a trump suit (H, D, S, C): j
Please enter a valid suit.
Please choose a trump suit (H, D, S, C): HH
Correct
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would be better off 
(generally speaking anyway) using `fgets` for the user input. `scanf` is problematic by comparision. fgets reads input in this case from stdin  (the keyboard). Now it's simple to remove any newline character and test the length.

```
char getTrump(){
  const int suitSize = 12;
  char suit[suitSize];
  bool correct = false;
  memset(suit, 0, suitSize);

  do
  {
    printf("Please choose a trump suit (H, D, S, C): ");
    fgets(suit, suitSize-1, stdin);

    if (suit[strlen(suit)-1] == '\n')
        suit[strlen(suit)-1] = '\0';

    // check input length only one char
    if (strlen(suit) == 1 && isValidSuit(*suit) == 1){
        printf("Correct\n");
        correct = true;
    }
    else{
        printf("Please enter a valid suit.\n");
    }
  } while (!correct);
  return *suit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, fgets/this code seems a lot more robust in comparison with scanf. We have only covered scanf in class regarding user input, so I wasn't really sure how to approach using fgets. I really appreciate your answer, however, why is memset necessary? Also I was under the impression there were no boolean values in c

Comment: Global and static variables are initialised to zeros. But variables defined on the stack (as in this case) are not. You are right though, memset  not needed in this case - `fgets` adds a null character at end of input. `bool` is available in C99, but requires `#include <stdbool.h>`.  C99 Compilation example `gcc --std=c99 file.c`

Answer (score 1):

> if they enter HH, or SS (which is invalid) it thinks it's correct.

Of course because when you give input `HH`, the `scanf(" %c", &trump);` read first `H` of input in `trump` variable and left the second `H` of input in the input buffer. After this, the `getchar()` in `while` loop reads the leftover user input. The `isValidSuit()` finds `H` as value of `trump` variable and returns `1`. Hence, you are getting `Correct` for `HH` or `SS` input.

To fix this problem, you can check if the input if more than `1` character and that character is not newline character than prompt user to enter valid input, like this:

```
char getTrump(){
    char trump;
    char ch;

    char correct = 1;
    while(correct == 1){
        printf("Please choose a trump suit (H, D, S, C): ");
        scanf(" %c", &trump);
        if (getchar() != '\n') {
            while(getchar() != '\n');
            printf("Please enter a valid suit.\n");
            continue;
        }
    .......
    .......
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful in understanding how c is actually working with scanf and stuff. It is also a simple implementation which I appreciate.